# Firestore iOS - Array not populating on first call

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a friend array but when the screen first loads the array does not have any elements in it, but when I close the screen and go back into it, it finally shows up. How do I make it show on the first try?

Model:

```
    func addFriendObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
        removeFriendListener = CURRENT_USER_FRIENDS_REF.addSnapshotListener{ snapshot, error in
            self.friendList.removeAll()
            
            guard error == nil else {
                #if DEBUG
                    print("Error retreiving collection")
                #endif
                return
            }
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let id = document.documentID
                self.getUser(id, completion: { (user) in
                    self.friendList.append(user)
                })
            }
        }
        
        update()
    }
```

View controller:

```
    FriendSystem.system.addFriendObserver { () in
        FriendSystem.system.friendList.sort(by: {$0.username < $1.username})
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print(FriendSystem.system.friendList)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addSnapshotListener` is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the query is complete.  The listener will be invoked some time later with the results.  It looks like your code attempts to update the UI before `self.friendList` contains any data.  You will have to wait to render your UI until after the query finishes.  That means probably calling update() inside the callback rather than immediately after `addSnapshotListener` returns.